# Environment variable access AWS

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services

Why can my application not access environment variables that I have set? I deployed a WAR to AWS and set environment variables via ssh, but am unable to read them in. This process works in my dev environment, so not sure why it won't work in production. Any ideas? I am on a windows box locally and a linux box in production, but I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables should be set so that the user your app's process is running as can see them.

You say you are deploying a WAR - so my guess is that it's on tomcat - you could add your environment variables to the setenv.sh script in the tomcat/bin directory.

Sample setenv.sh contents with a few options for tomcat and an environment variable:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xmx1024M -XX:PermSize=512M -Duser.timezone=UTC -DgeoIPFile='/some/path/to/GeoIP.dat' -DxafileDir='/tmp/xafile' -DuploadDir='/path/to/uploads/dir'"
export MYENVVAR="12345"
```

Comment: It is tomcat. I don't see a tomcat/bin directory. Do I need to stop my server to access it? How would I go about creating that script?

Comment: What linux distribution are you running on your EC2 instance? Look for tomcat in /opt/tomcat perhaps, or check the documentation for the image you used to create the EC2 instance for details of where tomcat is installed. Tomcat already comes with this script, so you shouldn't have to create it.

Comment: if it's ubuntu perhaps try looking for config files in /etc/tomcat6

Comment: ...or for bin directory under /usr/share/tomcat7 (or possibly /usr/share/tomcat6 if you are not running tomcat 7) (assuming ubuntu)